# JanusGraph adding edge doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to add vertices and edges to JanusGraph and it doesn't seem to work as expected. I am using Cassandra and Elasticsearch as backend. I am able to add vertices. I use code below to test if vertices and edges added.

```
this.graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties");
trv = graph.traversal()
trv.V().count()
//Returns count and runs as expected
trv.E().count()
//Returns 0 even though I added the edges
```

I use code below to add edges.

```
tx = this.graph.newTransaction();
Long vertexId = companyMap.get(Integer.parseInt(record.get("ASSIGNEE")));
Vertex assignee = this.traversal.V(vertexId).next();
Vertex patent = this.traversal.V(patentId).next();
patent.addEdge("assigned_to", assignee);
tx.commit();
```

I changed code to according to Jason's comment below. Now I create new traversal object whenever i want to get existing vertex then add edge. It seems to be working now.

```
GraphTraversalSource trv = this.graph.traversal();
Long vertexId = companyMap.get(Integer.parseInt(record.get("ASSIGNEE")));
Vertex assignee = this.traversal.V(vertexId).next();
Vertex patent = this.traversal.V(patentId).next();
patent.addEdge("assigned_to", assignee);
trv.tx().commit();
```

Comment: FWIW, works for me as seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pluradj/07956ffbc8871db81b85a0aa4dc49b32). Any more details you can add to your scenario?

Comment: I create single traversal object to add everything do you think that would make difference what kind of details should i supply thank you so much

Comment: a full example would be helpful, like I showed in my gist

Answer (score 0):

use the latest janusgraph 0.3.x version, which includes examples of usage for different backends